# How to redirect or disable mobile access to site?

Tags: html, redirect, mobile

I am building a very basic html-only site to display a specifically-sized project that is really only meant to be viewed on a computer. I seem to only find information on how to make your site mobile-friendly, but I want the opposite. Is there a way to redirect mobile users to a completley separate page, or to not allow the site to be viewed from mobile at all?

A lot of the answers that I have seen involve javascript or jquery but I would like to avoid that if possible

Comment: This can easily be accomplished with CSS media queries, to apply a `display: none` to basically everything if the screen is below a certain size. Consider a message that explains why, though.

Answer (score 0):

Without using javascript you can't redirect to an other page when the user is in mobile. However you can change the display property in the body tag when a specific screen size is detected like this:

```css
/* Default styles for the body */
body {
  display: block; /* or any other default value */
}

/* Media query for screens with a maximum width of 600px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    display: none; /* or any other value for mobile screens */
  }
}
```

Or, if you need to redirect to another page, you have to use JavaScript:
Use this code in your page to redirect to another url (or page) if a mobile browser detected:

```
<script>
  window.mobileCheck = function () {
    let check = false;
    (function (a) {
      if (
        /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(
          a
        ) ||
        /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
          a.substr(0, 4)
        )
      )
        check = true;
    })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
    return check;
  };

  // The above function was imported from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/19099302 by Michael Zaporozhets

  if (window.mobileCheck()) {
    window.location.href = "mobile.html"; // Replace this mobile.html with the page url you want to redirect
  }
</script>
```

The [`window.mobileCheck()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/19099302) will check if the user is in a mobile browser. Then changing the `windows.location.href` will redirect to an other page. (Remember to replace that `"mobile.html"` to the url/page you want to redirect.)

> [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11381730/19099302)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    $iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
    $berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
    $ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

    if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) { 
       echo "REDIRECT LINK HERE"; 
    } 
?>
```

just redirects if you are in anything other than a phone.

Comment: `$palmpre` should probably indicate to you that this is some *very* outdated code, lol.

Comment: yeah whatever ig ur right